# Store a values from HTML input into a php variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="gencyolcu" />

    <title>Untitled 8</title>
</head>

<body>

   Date:<br />
  <input type="date" id="sdate"/><br />
 <button onclick="fun()">Click me</button>

<script>

var js_x =document.getElementById('sdate');

</script>

</body>
</html>

<?php
 echo $php_x;
?>
```

I want to use the date to fetch data using php.
How can I store the value I get from the date input tag in the php variable ?

Comment: Ajax, the answer is ajax.

Comment: You must post it to your server with a `<form>`

Answer (score 2):

Php is for server side, it doesn't know about anything happening in the client side unless you send a request to the server, to send the variable to the Php you need to call the Php page and send it as a parameter or you can use AJAX if you don't want to refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible , use AJAX !

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the date information to the server.  This can be done primarily through a `<form>` submit with an `action` attribute set to the PHP script.

Alternatively you could do it through `AJAX`.  This uses an asynchronous call to retrieve data from the server without the browser having to refresh the entire content.

I'm guessing from your question you have limited experience working with PHP.  I would recommend you look at handling form submission and then move onto `AJAX`.

An example form submission tutorial: http://myphpform.com/php-form-tutorial.php

A quick Google will bring up lots of tutorials and examples.